# Problem with saving first element to array in todo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have problem with my simple todo App in React with react-hooks.

When i get my inputValue and try to assign it to object and save in to my items Array, it doesn't work.

( The first assign after onSubmit action is empty array, and i completely don't know why. But the second button action work fine.

Can someone please help me out here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/young-sun-r2jdp?fontsize=14

Comment: if you want to do console first you need to spread the array into another as setItems will work as async at point of console.log items doesn't have values in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing `console.log` right after setting the new items, but React makes updates on new re-render, so you won't see the changes before the component re-renders.

To test, you can render the current items by adding this below your `button` element:

```
          <p>Got items:</p>
            {items.map((item, i) => (
              <div key={i}>{item.name}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought my component will render after onClick ;p But now i understand, thanks :)

Comment: Or by adding console statement before return function. It will call every time component renders.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that sort of side effects(like console.log) in the useEffect hook, it will run after every `items` variable update and will log you the right thing

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(items);
  }, [items])
```

Comment: Items is an array and useEffect does a shallow comparison i.e. this will cause multiple unnecessary renders.

Comment: From what I know the `setItems` function will update an array in an immutable way and since the reference will be new, it will update correctly and effect will run only on actual state updates. The useEffect itself doesn't invoke re-renders as it's just doing the console.log so I don't understand what are you talking about

Comment: Sorry, I meant it will cause calling the callback in `useEffect` to be run on every re-render. Generally using arrays/objects as a second argument to `useEffect` is a bad practice: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14324#issuecomment-441489421

Comment: I see where you are coming from, makes sense. Thanks for the explanation, but for this example really we can omit the second argument at all as Chazzy just wanted to see the actual items array on every update so it makes sense to call the effect on every render, isn't it? Just like you suggested to render an array on every render

Comment: In that case we need to pass an empty array, since not passing a second argument at all will again call the callback on every render.

Comment: But then the console.log will incorrectly display only the state on the first render and will not do it on the further updates. We just have to run the effect on every render to see the current state in the console and it's totally okay in this case